# Map FireStore Collection to Java POJO

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using FireStore database and I am wondering how can I convert these collections from "Hospital/DcbtizNr0ADNNnd0evlN" into a Java object? I mean, how could I search (with 1 query) for a specific Hospital and get all its documents and collections mapped to a java object?

[image: This is my database structure]

Pacientes/Fichas/Profissionais follows almost the same structure:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can easily map a `QuerySnapshot` to a list of objects, assuming your app contains a `Hospital` POJO class that matches the data:

```
db.collection("Hospital")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Convert the whole snapshot to a POJO list
                    List<Hospital> objects = task.getResult().toObjects(Hospital.class);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

The Hospital class could look like this:

```
public class Hospital {

  // These can either be public properties, or private properties
  // with standard-named getters and setters like getAvenida() and
  // setAvenida()
  public String avenida;
  public String bairro;
  public String cep;
  public String cidade;
  public String estado;
  public String name;
  public String numero;

  // Empty constructor required
  Hospital() {}

}
```

reference:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/android/QuerySnapshot.html#toObjects(java.lang.Class)

Comment: I forgot to be a little more specific. How can I convert a collection into Pojo? For example, what kind of java structure could I map Pacientes?

Comment: And what about Hospital's collections? How can I map them?

Comment: Those cannot be mapped all at once.  Queries in Cloud Firestore are shallow, data from subcollections must be retrieved separately.